# refresh uitableview on button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, refresh

I have 2 views in my app
1st view: tableview and button(update) 
2nd view: detail view

I want to refresh table in 1st view when I am pressing update button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to reload the data if you come back from the DetailView?

then put it in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

---

then connect your button in interfacebuilder or with

```
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadTableView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

to this method

```
- (IBAction)reloadTableView:(id)sender {
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: no...i want refresh table when i am pressing UPDATE button in same view......i alredy tried your solution but this is not what i am looking for...do you know what should i have to do to refresh table on button click..thank you

Comment: @Pooja maybe you should try to improve your question. for me it's not completly clear what you want.

Comment: and where should i write this   [yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadTableView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: @fluchtpunkt: please check it once again.

Comment: you put it where you create your button. If you create the button in interface builder you have to connect your button in interface builder with reloadTableView:. Therefor you have to put the definition of reloadTableView: in your header. And you should definitely search for a tutorial about the basics of iphone app design.

Comment: ok, here i figure out, i was not updating array values..and now its work fine [tableview reloadData];